# How #define works in Programming when define has value with operator?

Tags: c++, c

I am facing problem to understand how #define works.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define x 6+3
int main(){

int i;
i=x;    //9
printf("%d\n",i);
i=x*x;  //27
printf("%d\n",i);
i=x*x*x;   //45
printf("%d\n",i);
i=x*x*x*x;    //63
printf("%d\n",i);

return 0;
}
```

If I use `#define x 6+3` the output is 9 27 45 63

If I use `#define x (6+3)` the output is 9 81 729 6561

Comment: To learn, I suggest that you do the macro expansion by hand to understand what happens.

Comment: #define works by text substitution.

Comment: From above comment, to get you started `i=x*X` -> `i=6+3*6+3`

Comment: Use: `gcc  -E filename.c`

Comment: It's textual substitution.  That's why you never write macros like the one you have.  Instead, you wrap the body in parentheses to prevent unintended association.

Comment: [The documentation is here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#define` simply replaces the character token (in your case `x`) with what you defined it to be.
So your example would look like this after the preprocessor did his work:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define x 6+3
int main(){

    int i;
    i=6+3;    //9
    printf("%d\n",i);
    i=6+3*6+3;  //27
    printf("%d\n",i);
    i=6+3*6+3*6+3;   //45
    printf("%d\n",i);
    i=6+3*6+3*6+3*6+3;    //63
    printf("%d\n",i);

    return 0;

}
```

And if you look over it you see why e.g. the second example is 27 instead of 81 (* before +).

On the other hand if you write (6+3) it will be 9*9 and thats what you would expect it to be.

Comment: "*replaces the variable*" is somewhat misleading, as the pre-processor does ***not** know* about "variables". The latter phrase better read "replaces the character token".

Answer (score 2):

This is a case of **operator precedence**. You can study about it a bit. I am describing on this matter as follow.

If you use

```
#define x 6+3
```

then

```
x = 6+3= 9

x*x = 6+3 * 6+3 = 6+18+3 = 27 (as * has higher precedence as operator than + ; so 3*6 will be evaluated earlier )
```

and similarly goes on.

Now if you use

```
#define x (6+3)
```

then

```
x = (6+3) = 9

x*x = (6+3)*(6+3) = 9*9 = 81
```

and similarly goes on.

So my suggestion is to use brackets always for better readability and understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Name of macro is replaced by the contents. It means that

```
#define x 6+3
x*x*x*x = 6+3*6+3*6+3*6+3 = 6+18+18+18+3
```

when you define x as (6+3) - (6+3) inserted. It means that

```
#define x (6+3)
x*x*x*x = (6+3)*(6+3)*(6+3)*(6+3) = 9*9*9*9
```

Read about [C Preprocessor and Macros](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-preprocessor-macros)

Answer (score 1):

macro expansion is a text replacement.  So

```
 #define x 6 + 3
 #define y (6+3)
```

Gives the following

```
 printf( "%d %d\n", x , y );        // 6 +3 , (6+3) is 9 and 9
 printf( "%d %d\n", x *x , y * y ); //  6 + 3 * 6 + 3,  (6+3) * (6+3)
                                    //  6 + 18 + 3   ,  9     *  9
                                    //       27      ,  81
```